# Indenting a heredoc in a Groovy source file

Tags: groovy

I'd like to preserve the expected indentation in my source file when using a heredoc but, at the same time, have the contents of the here document not indented when rendered. E.g. the following

```
// myscript.groovy
if ( someCondition ) {
  println """
  some multi-line
  content
  """
}
```

will print an indented output e.g.

```
$ groovy myscript.groovy

    some multi-line
    content
```

but instead I'd like it to just print the content unindented as follows

```
$ groovy myscript.groovy

some multi-line
content
```

how can this be accomplished in Groovy?

Bash has the `<<-STRING` heredoc definition to accomplish this but I've not been able to find anything similar for Groovy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [stripMargin](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.0/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#stripMargin(java.lang.CharSequence))

```
if ( someCondition ) {
  println """
            |some multi-line
            |content
            |""". stripMargin()
}
```